# how to use zip efficiently to iterate parallelly in multiple lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-zip

Is there any way that while using the ZIP function we can provide some default value to parallel elements which are not present and still print the entire stuff?

eg, for the below code **6** from **list a** getting missed but I don't want that to happen

```
a = [1,2,4,6]
b = [[1,3],[4,7],[6,1]]
for a,(b,c) in zip(a,b):
  print(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip_longest` to provide default values for missing elements in your code:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [1, 2, 4, 6]
b = [[1, 3], [4, 7], [6, 1]]

for a, (b, c) in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=(0, 0)):
    print(a, b, c)
```

This will print the following output:

```
1 1 3
2 4 7
4 6 1
6 0 0
```

In the example, `zip_longest` function adds a value of 0 for the missing elements in the input `iterables`. By default the `zip_longest` function will add a `None` value.  You can change the filled value by specifying it in the `fillvalue` argument.

Comment: Did you try running this?

Comment: Yes i tested it out on python 3.10.6

Comment: Maybe the edit, the original answer raised an exception. You should test your answers before posting them.

Comment: Minor correction: `zip_longest`'s default value is `None`, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The zip_longest function from itertools should achieve exactly what you want:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [1,2,4,6]
b = [[1,3],[4,7],[6,1]]
for a,(b,c) in zip_longest(a,b, fillvalue=("NaN1", "NaN2")):
   print(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

x = [1,2,4,6]
y = [[1,3],[4,7],[6,1]]
for x,(y,z) in zip_longest(x,y, fillvalue=("NaN1", "NaN2")):

   print(x,y,z)
```